# How to run NASA applet on Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, applet

I am trying to use the NASA Applet from https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/tunoret.html . I downloaded a zip file, extracted it as a folder, then somehow managed to open that folder in Eclipse. Now, when I try to run the applet, I get the error message below.

> Error: Could not find or load main class sun.applet.AppletViewer
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.applet.AppletViewer

This is a link to the picture of the IDE and what file I right-clicked to try to run it. My coding experience is limited to simple python and Matlab commands, so help on any step of the way would be appreciated

[image: Image of IDE]

Comment: Java applets are a dead technology. AppletViewer is no longer included in current verstions of Java.

Comment: Well, that sucks. I guess I gotta go create my own code :/ Thanks mate